# OpenCart 3.0.2 | Не изменяется файл product.twig

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Занимался превращением html шаблона в полностью рабочий шаблон для opencart. До некоторого момента все идеально редактировалось, т.е все кэши отключены. При попытке же редактировать файл product.twig никаких изменений не происходит от слова вообще. Я пробовал даже на родной теме экспериментировать результата ноль! Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с похожей проблемой? Код страницы скидывать не вижу смысла.

Comment: Каким способом редактируете файлы?

Comment: Новый шаблон редактировал по FTP, дефолтный как через админ панель, так и по FTP. Ни в одном из случаем ничего не изменилось

Comment: Разобрался со своей проблемой, оказалось забыл рефрешнуть модификаторы.

Comment: Собственно это я и хотел вам предложить)

Comment: Такая же проблема, но после рефреша модификаторов всё равно ничего не менется